# How to pass a CGRect frame value to an custom transition animation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation

I am trying to make a custom expand viewcontroller animation in iOS.

It's a iPad application and has a big square button of size 160*160 in the home screen. I have connected a modal segue to the next viewcontroller scene. What I am trying to achieve is when I tap on the UIButton the destination viewcontroller should expand from the button and shall be animated to full screen with animation completion.

I have subclassed NSObject and created ExpandAnimationController, implemented transitionDuration and animateTransition methods. But the I am stuck at a point to determine the initial frame for the destination viewcontroller's view.

I know for one button I can set frame statically but where in a scenario appears that there are multiple buttons and each button has to a modal segue to a different view controller than how can I pass the buttons frame to the animation controller to set the initial view frame.

I am doing this only for learning purpose after trying raywanderlich's custom view controller transition tutorial. So the problem now is passing a frame object from "Source controller to Animation controller". I've already searched, internet is not much populated with custom transition issues. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code I've tried, in ExpandAnimationController,

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    // 1. Fetch all the required objects.
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    CGRect finalFrame = toVC.view.frame;

    // 2. Set initial frames.
    // This is where I am stuck.
    CGRect initialFrame = CGRectZero;
    toVC.view.frame = initialFrame;
    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    // 3. Do the animation.
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        fromVC.view.alpha = 0.5;
        toVC.view.alpha = 0.5;
        toVC.view.frame = finalFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromVC.view.alpha = 1.0;
        toVC.view.alpha = 1.0;
        toVC.view.frame = finalFrame;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
```

In the source controller I've adopted `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, created a ExpandAnimationController instance and used like below,

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return _expandAnimationController;
}
```

But after - `prepareForSegue` is called I want to pass the sender button frame to the transition animation controller.

Thanks in advance, Happy coding !!

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you have done so far

Comment: @Lefteris Hey I have edited the post and added code as you asked, check out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches on how you could do this, like an iVar to your transition or transitioning delegate that you could pass in the button rect, but I'm going to suggest a simpler approach (although with a caveat):

First assign a unique Tag to your `UIButton` either by code, or in Interface Builder.
In this example I'm using the 111 tag:

In your `- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext` you can get a reference to that button from your ViewController:

```
CGRect myButtonRect = CGRectZero;
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton*)[fromVC.view viewWithTag:111];
if (myButton) {
    myButtonRect = myButton.frame;
    NSLog(@"button Frame:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(myButtonRect));
}
```

What's the caveat?
If you are using the same animation to transition back, the From and To View controllers are going to be reversed.

Also if you use the same Transition on another View Controller and that View Controller has the same tag number for another object, you will get that object and not your Button.

So if you use this approach make sure to use a globally Unique Tag for your entire App, like 32565 (random number here that is big enough so you won't re-use it again)

Now if you have multiple buttons, you cannot use the above approach, so use an iVar to your custom transition:

```
@interface MyCustomTransition : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect initialFrame;

@end
```

Then in the view controller you are using your custom transition, just pass in the frame:

```
MyCustomTransition *myTransition = [MyCustomTransition new];
myTransition.initialFrame = myButton.frame;
```

And finally in your `- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext` get the iVar value from `self.initialFrame`

Comment: Hey thanks. That gives me a bit of idea how to proceed further however, the actual situation is as I previously stated, i.e multiple buttons. I have 4 buttons and I am navigating to the same viewcontroller from all the 4 buttons. And I want the initial frame of the viewcontroller to be of the tapped sender button. So using tag becomes inconvenient but I think of another approach to set the tag of the button sender in -prepareForSegue method using a global static integer variable and using the same to retrieve the object n hence frame in the other class. Do u have any other better approach ?

Comment: Hey thanks, actually I've created already a frame object in animation controller and then just lost in my thought. Lol.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `CGRect` to `NSValue`  and put it into sender.

```
    // Send it like this
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier" sender:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:yourFrame]];
```

Also you can retrieve it like this

```
    // Retrieve it
    CGRect frame = [sender CGRectValue];
```

Comment: I am not trying to get the value in my destination viewcontroller or in prepareForSegue method. I am trying to pass it to a intermediate AnimationViewcontroller. But what you are suggesting is actually different scenario.